# Could not find namespace 'system' and 'Xamarin' in project UWP cross-plateform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I am new to Xamarin, i have create a projet (cross-plateform) in project.UWP i get lot off error that told me:

could not found namespace 'System' and 'Xamarin'

i want to add refereces but i did not found them

Comment: why do you need reference Xamarin in uwp? as far as i know Xamarin is for android/mac, while uwp is for Microsoft's os.

Comment: Thank you Lei Yang for replying me, as i said whene i have created new project cross-plateform i have solution with 4 project and in the last one (UWP) here where i have this error message

Comment: Have you tried to restore the nuget package (right click the solution -> Restore NuGet Package)?

Comment: You are SO right ... why do I need to reference Xamarin in ... anything?  Thousands and thousands of wasted hours trying to bludgeon unworkable samples and example into life, hundreds and hundreds of relentless system crashes and hangs, incomplete, incoherent and confusing documentation, upgrades and releases by the score, 99% of my time wasted fighting the development system rather than the business problem, the phrases 'quality assurance' and 'quality control' completely alien to the spotty-faced kids who inflicted this mish-mash twaddle on the development community. You are SO right...